# in a dictionary of list's , how to remove all elements except the max element

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, filter

In the below mentioned dictionary, which has list's as values of dictionary, how to keep only max element and remove rest of the elements and about the list containing single element has to be kept intact(since its the only element) and output the result into a new dictionary

my_dict  =  {'audi':[99,67,45], 'porsche':[87,76,54], 'ferrari':[76]}

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you show code on what you did to find a working solution for your problem? And where did it fail?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
my_dict = {"audi": [99, 67, 45], "porsche": [87, 76, 54], "ferrari": [76]}

out = {k: [max(v)] for k, v in my_dict.items()}
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'audi': [99], 'porsche': [87], 'ferrari': [76]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for car, list_ in my_dict.items():
    my_dict[car] = [max(list_)]
```

This assumes that all values in the lists are integers.

A one liner could be:

```
new_dict = {car: [max(list_)] for car, list_ in my_dict.items()}
```